# Resizing using the Canvas's id?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

Can you make your canvas resize to the page width using the style in the html of the canvas id?

And then in your js for the canvas just resize listeners based on the size of the canvas at the current time?

I have many of my variables and listeners hardcoded just wondering what is the fastest method of solving this :)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, a good starting thing would be not to take the entire page width, but a `div`container. That way if you end up putting your app in a website or anything, your code will adapt to any container. If you want it to be the full page, this container can just be a 100% width/height absolute with no padding/margin.

Please also note that there are two sizes for a canvas :

- The HTML size, which is the size you will draw on "programmatically"
- The CSS size, which is the size it will be displayed, independently of the other size (and it will resize it, causing potential distortions)

Based on that, you can know an element's screen width using jquery `$("#myID").width()` or `height()`, which applies to the canvas too. Based on this you can set whatever size you want in html and/or css :

```
$("#myCanvas").width = 400; // The size you will draw on
$("#myCanvas").css('width', '800'); // The size it will be displayed (2x scale in X in that case)
```

Then for resizing you have multiple solutions :

- **CSS full stretching** : You use your canvas with whatever size you'd like to code in, and  then resize it in CSS to use the full page width, that is basically putting the css at 100% width / height
- **CSS stretching with aspect ratio** : My prefered solution, which consists of resizing the canvas in CSS, but by keeping the original application's aspect ratio (and putting black borders on the rest of the screen, like in large-screen movies)
- **Pure canvas resizing** : This method won't destroy graphics, but it has the big cost of making you think all your drawing with any size possible. Instead of having a fixed size canvas that is resized by the browser, you will have to multiply all your drawing sizes and positions according to the screen size, which can end up being very boring, and problematic if not thought soon in the development.

As an exemple here is my [canvas manager](https://github.com/Malharhak/Raclette/blob/master/RacletteGame/Raclette/Rendering/CanvasManager.js), with CSS aspect ratio resizing. It is not documented and may not suit your need, but it can give you some ideas